# httpresponse resp= httpClient.execute(httpPost) hangs in uploading file from android to webservice(wcf)

Tags: android, file-upload, http-post, httpclient, network-protocols

I am using android code given below in a service (subclass of IntentService) with it's saparate thread but this code works sometimes cool but sometimes not. That means reliability issue. after debuging I found that code hangs sometimes at httpClient.execute(httppost). How can I make it accurate to work in any condition? Thanks in advance.

httpresponce code

```
final HttpResponse resp;
            final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();      
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverUrl);

            try {
                ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(file_uri, "r");
                InputStream in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(file_uri);
                CountingInputStreamEntity entity = new CountingInputStreamEntity(in, fileDescriptor.getStatSize());
                entity.setUploadListener(this);
                entity.setContentType("application/gpx+xml");
                //entity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Log.i("FOO", "About to call httpClient.execute");
                resp = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Uploading Completed", no_rx+" Rx Uploaded", contentIntent);
                    no_rx = 0;
                    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
                    Log.i("FOO", "All done");
                } else {
                    Log.i("FOO", "Screw up with http - " + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                }
                resp.getEntity().consumeContent();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

complete code

```
public class UploadService extends IntentService{

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Notification notification;

    public UploadService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public UploadService(){
        super("UploadService");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //Uri uri  = intent.getData();
        String[] all_path_sel = intent.getStringArrayExtra("all_path_sel");
        for(String s : all_path_sel){
            File f = new File(s);
            Uri file_uri = Uri.fromFile(f);         
            String serverUrl = Constants.BASIC_URL+Constants.ACTION_UPLOADFILE
                    +LoginActivity.user.getUserUniqueId()+"/"+f.getName();
            Thread t = new Thread(new BackgroundThread(this, file_uri,serverUrl));
            t.start();          
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    int no_rx = 0;
    private class BackgroundThread implements Runnable, CountingInputStreamEntity.UploadListener {

        Context context;
        Uri file_uri;
        String serverUrl;
        int lastPercent = 0;


        public BackgroundThread(Context context, Uri file_uri,String serverUrl) {
            this.context = context;
            this.file_uri = file_uri;
            this.serverUrl = serverUrl;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            no_rx++;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


            notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    "Uploading Rx "+no_rx, System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.flags = notification.flags
                    | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext()
                    .getPackageName(), R.layout.upload_progress_bar);
            notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
            notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 100,0, false);

            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

            Log.i("FOO", "Notification started");

            final HttpResponse resp;
            final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();      
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverUrl);

            try {
                ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(file_uri, "r");
                InputStream in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(file_uri);
                CountingInputStreamEntity entity = new CountingInputStreamEntity(in, fileDescriptor.getStatSize());
                entity.setUploadListener(this);
                entity.setContentType("application/gpx+xml");
                //entity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Log.i("FOO", "About to call httpClient.execute");
                resp = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Uploading Completed", no_rx+" Rx Uploaded", contentIntent);
                    no_rx = 0;
                    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
                    Log.i("FOO", "All done");
                } else {
                    Log.i("FOO", "Screw up with http - " + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                }
                resp.getEntity().consumeContent();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onChange(int percent) {
            if(percent > lastPercent) {
                notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 100, percent, false);
                notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
                lastPercent = percent;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Activity Code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_picker);
        setTitle("");
        initImageLoader();//load image in imageviewer
        init();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            mCamera.mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
        } else {
            mCamera.mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
        }

    }

private void initImageLoader() {
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                this).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).memoryCache(
                new WeakMemoryCache());

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);
    }

    private void init() {       
        gridGallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridGallery);
        gridGallery.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        adapter = new ImageGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), imageLoader);
        adapter.setMultiplePick(false);
        gridGallery.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
        viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild(1);                      
        mImageBitmap = null;        
        gridGallery.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        gridGallery.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {          
            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode,
                    MenuItem item) {
                // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.delete_file:
                        SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter.getSelectedIds();
                        for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                            if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                                ImageItem selecteditem = adapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                                //adapter.remove(selecteditem);
                                mImagePicker.remSelImage_updadr(selecteditem);
                            }
                        }
                        // Close CAB                        
                        mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }               
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode,
                    Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu for the CAB
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_file_picker, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode) {
                adapter.removeSelection();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode,
                    Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode mode,
                    int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                final int checkedCount = gridGallery.getCheckedItemCount();
                mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
                adapter.toggleSelection(position);
            }           
        });     
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImagePickerActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle(Constants.ALERT_FILEUPLOAD); 
                alert.setMessage(Constants.ALERT_CONFIRMATION);
                alert.setPositiveButton(Constants.ALERT_CONFIRMATION_OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {          
                    new Thread(){
                        public void run(){                  
                            mFileUploader = new FileUploader(mImagePicker.imgArLst);
                            mFileUploader.uploadFiles_withService();            
                        }
                    }.start();
                  }
                });

        private class FileUploader{
            private ArrayList<ImageItem> imgArList;                         

            FileUploader(ArrayList<ImageItem> imgArList){
                this.imgArList = imgArList;
            }

            private void uploadFiles_withService() {            
                Intent intent = new Intent(ImagePickerActivity.this, UploadService.class);
                ArrayList<String> arrStrLstPath = new ArrayList<String>();          
                for(ImageItem im : mImagePicker.imgArLst){
                    String path = im.getSdCardPath();
                    arrStrLstPath.add(path);
                }
                String[] all_path_sel = arrStrLstPath.toArray(new String[arrStrLstPath.size()]);            
                intent.putExtra("all_path_sel", all_path_sel);
                startService(intent);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        mImagePicker.clearAllImage_updadr();
                        //prgd.dismiss();
                    }
                });         
                }
            }               
        }
```

Comment: did u find solution?

Answer (score 0):

use below class to upload image

```
public class GlobalMultiPart extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private static final String TAG = GlobalMultiPart.class.getSimpleName() ;
        Uri uri;
        HashMap<String, String> params;
        String Url;
        InputStream inputStream;
        String displayName, imageKey;
        boolean isInputStream = false;

        public interface OnResponse {
            void onResponse(String result);

            void onError(String error);
        }

        OnResponse onResponse;


        public GlobalMultiPart(Uri uri, HashMap<String, String> params, String url, OnResponse onResponse, String imageKey) {
            if (params == null) {
                params = new HashMap<>();
            }
            this.uri = uri;
            this.params = params;
            this.Url = url;
            this.onResponse = onResponse;
            this.imageKey = imageKey;
            try {
                readMetaData(uri);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            uploadImage();
            return null;
        }


        public void uploadImage() {
            String Response = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Url);
                post.setEntity(hashMapToMultipart());
                HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(post);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response1.getEntity();
                Response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                Log.i(SetupProfile.class.getSimpleName(), Response);
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (Response == null)
                onResponse.onError("An error occurred");
            else
                onResponse.onResponse(Response);

        }

        public MultipartEntity hashMapToMultipart() {
            MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();

            if (uri != null) {
                ContentBody cbFile1 = new InputStreamBody(inputStream, displayName);
                mpEntity.addPart(imageKey, cbFile1);
            }


            try {

                for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                    mpEntity.addPart(key, new StringBody(params.get(key)));
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mpEntity;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        private void readMetaData(Uri uri) {
            try {

                inputStream = AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                isInputStream = true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                displayName = uri.getLastPathSegment();
 Cursor cursor = AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null) {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
              Log.e(TAG,"Cursor on multipart null");
            }
        }


    }
```

Sample

```
new GlobalMultiPart(uri, params, url, this, imageTag).execute();
```

imageTag key for image

Hope it works